# improving sql query in the case of many ORs

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have an SQL query which can have around 1.5k of IDs OR'ed in the following form. They are the IDs of people I have and they are individually selectable, hence the many ORs when everyone is selected. Is it better to just **SELECT** everyone's ID then put it in the **AND** condition, **UNION** instead of **OR**, or perhaps use **IN** to bunch up all IDs, since the user may select everyone accept 1 person. Thanks.

```
 ...
AND (
      (UserID = '53b95690-22d8-44a2-ad56-919cb4037218')
   OR (UserID = '87b7fc0c-28f4-4f2e-9909-066df42245fa')
   OR (UserID  = '98c1b5e3-6ba5-4bd9-b8f5-d3b2221e3e3a')
   OR...
```

**EDIT**: The complete query, as requested;

```
SELECT *
FROM Mail WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Active= 1
AND Company= '1d034e8b-0122-4531-8795-895d9287920f' 
AND (
    CompanyDivisionID= '129bcca1-b1d8-4a9e-8152-0b9e936c9d01'
    OR CompanyDivisionID= '1bf4023d-22a3-4520-b751-7842576f42b7'
    )
AND (
    (DestinationUserID = '53b95690-22d8-44a2-ad56-919cb4037218')
    OR (DestinationUserID = '87b7fc0c-28f4-4f2e-9909-066df42245fa')
    OR (DestinationUserID = '98c1b5e3-6ba5-4bd9-b8f5-d3b2221e3e3a')
            ...
            ...
            ...
    OR (DestinationUserID = '8c78fc05-7969-48fd-9b30-774e5d9a70bd')
    OR (DestinationUserID  = 'e7b76096-fe7d-44b8-9158-8293ac609471')
    OR (DestinationUserID = '8a6b7385-4339-43fb-b95b-a7b687982bcd')
    )  
ORDER BY SendingDate DESC
```

Comment: `IN` is transformed to `OR` by the optimizer, so that will make no difference. Are you working with parameters? What is the use of this selection?

Comment: I can have a bunch of userIDs (Guid) as parameters, depending on which ones the user selected. I recently found that they sometimes select all, which creates this situation.

Comment: @mechanicum : Can you show the complete query?

Comment: added complete query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a (temporary) table containing your selected UserIDs and join to that table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Mail WITH (NOLOCK)
     inner join SelectedUsers on mail.DestinationUserID = SelectedUsers.UserID
WHERE Active= 1
```